How to extract specific numbers with the given conditions in pandas
I have a sample data like this:
0                                   46X ⌀ 376_ 000 THRU
1                              SLOT ⌀250 X .750 LG ↧.03
2                               -2X .250-20-UNC-2B ↧.75
3                                            ⌀ 755+.002
4                            SLOT ⌀. 375 X 1.98 LG THRU
5                                    2X SLOT⌀ 256 _ 000
6                                                ↧ 1.00
7                                        50X ⌀ 265 THRU
8                              SLOT ⌀250 X .750 LG ↧.03
9                  SLOT ⌀ 505 +.002 WIDE X 3.86 LG THRU
10                                               42.±12
11                                        4X ⌀ 265 THRU
12                                     2X dĩa 06 THRU -
13                                          MARKED " A"
14                                                 THRU
15                                               -. 000
16                                              +.004 X
17                                           * X.356 LG
18                                    CHAMFER .05 X 45°
19                                           MARKED "B"
20                                           5 -. 000 Y
21                                               40.512
22                   NOTES: UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED:
23                                        4X R.378 THRU
24    2. FINISHED PART FREE OF MANUFACTURING RESIDUE...
25    3. CHEMICAL CLEAN PER SOLYNDRA CLEANING SPEC. ...
26    4\ DIE STAMP OR SCRIBE SOLYNDRA PART NUMBER, R...
27    5 BAG AND TAG WITH SOLYNDRA''S PART NUMBER AND...
28                                           2X FULL R.
29                                                 THRU
30                                              (2.823)
31                                   100 SHT XXXXX-1200
32                                             755+.003
33                                               (.197)
34                                                1.175
35    6. PACKAGE FOR SHIPPING AND STORAGE USING PROT...
36                   10X .375-16 UNC-2B THRU MARKED "C"
37                                                2.350
38                                                2.850
39                                                  ACO
40                                                COD B
41                                           4.75 2.750
42                                                 CO A
43                                                   OC
44                                                 OC B
45                                                  300
46                              10X .250-20 UNC-2B THRU
47                                            SIDE VIEW
48                                            10X 4.375
49                                             2X 4.250
50                                             8X 4.000
51                                                COADA
52                                                 DACA
53                                                  ACD
54                                             3X 2.823
55                                            23X 2.750

I have a column in a pandas DataFrame that contains text data. My task is to extract numbers from this text, but with two specific conditions:
1.Ignore any numbers that come before the letter 'X'.
Example: In the text "46X ⌀ 376_ 000 THRU", ignore the number 46 because it comes before 'X'.
2.Ignore any numbers that come after the symbols '+' or '-'.
Example: In the text "⌀ 755+.002", only the number 755 should be extracted because numbers after '+' are ignored.
Similarly, in the text "-2X .250-20-UNC-2B", ignore the number 20 because it comes after '-'.
My goal is to extract only the valid numbers from each text entry, based on these rules, and store the result in a new column in the DataFrame.
I tried to do:
df['integers'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(?<!X)\b\d+\b(?![+-])') 
df['integers'] = df['integers'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])

But the result is wrong.

What about the cases 3X 2.823 in your last row? What do you expect? 3?

I expect it to return 2.823 as it satisfies the condition

2.823 is not an integer, so I would have excluded it. So you are looking for numbers, be it integers or floats, right? Line 16 has +.004 X. According your conditions, the result would be empty, as the number, a float, is preceded with a +.

Your question needs precision because the conditions you give are not sufficient.

Please share the expected output for this input dataframe.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm sorry i said integers.All numbers included.                                                           ("46X ⌀ 376_ 000 THRU" → Extract [376, 0])
("⌀ 755+.002" → Extract [755])
("-2X .250-20-UNC-2B" → Extract [.250])                                                                             (+.004 X - The result should be empty).  I have edited the question to make it as clear as i can.

I was able to do it using this code:
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s.+-]', '', text))

def lz(text):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(\.\d+)', r'0\1', text)

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lz)

def ext(text):
    text = re.split(r'[+-]', text)[0]

    if 'X' in text:
        text = text.split('X')[-1]
    
    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', text)
    return numbers

df['Extracted Numbers'] = df['text'].apply(ext)



try using pd.Series.str with one of regex options e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html
